# Cant get Ajax Post data in view

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, django

I am sending a post request to view . everything is fine but no data is sent by ajax. In ajax call i checked variable there is data exist but not when its sent in view.

my ajax is

```
  $.post({
                url: '/projpost/message/{{project.id}}',
                data: {
                'message': message
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(message);   //working perfect


                }
            });
```

In view

```
@csrf_exempt
def message(request,id):
    print(request.POST['message'])
    return HttpResponse(content_type="application/json" )
```

But I am getting error

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /projpost/message/5/
'message'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
@csrf_exempt
def message(request,id):
    print(request.POST.get('message'))
    # or print(request.POST.get('message', ''))
    return HttpResponse(content_type="application/json" )
```

But if you will find that request.POST is empty, then you will have to work with only the **request**, not with request.POST

Comment: why it happened with  Post request ? Thanks Zollie now getting message :)

Comment: Using AJAX or javascript POST method, you have to receive and handle data in a different way in Django, not like with normal HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1):

The data is in `request.data`.

`request.POST` is only populated for when forms are submitted, or when you set the header to look like a form submission.